# How to write a locator for the text in between before:: and after::

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to write xpath for the below text and it works fine when highlighted in the chropath(plugin for chrome).But it is failing during run time though it is visible in application. I couldnt get right answer for this in google.Please help me resolve this.

```
<div class="abc">
::before
<content style="">Please fill out this field.</content>
::after
</div>
```

xpath : `//div[@class='abc']//content[contains(text(),\"Please fill out this field\")]`

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to get it with this: _//div[@class='abc']/content/text()_ ?

Comment: No, its failing in the run time.

Comment: Share the code you wrote with Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds a little strange, but sometimes the `text()` function will fail, when using the `.` token succeeds:

```js
let xpath = "//div[@class = 'abc']//content[contains(., 'Please fill out this field')]";
```

If this is still failing, make sure the `class` attribute doesn't contain multiple values, in which case you'll need to use `contains()` on the class as well:

```js
let xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'abc')]//content[contains(., 'Please fill out this field')]";
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared it is clear that the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) includes dynamic elements. So to identify the node with the text as **Please fill out this field.** you can use either of the following solution:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  div.abc content[style]
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  //div[@class='abc']//content[@style and contains(., 'Please fill out this field')]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes for text().

`//div[@class='abc']//content[contains(text(),'Please fill out this field')]`

Or

point directly to content like

```
//content[contains(text(),'Please fill out this field')]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need

```
//span[@class="order-num"]/text()
```

to get required value

Comment: Where is there an element with the class `order-num` anywhere in this question? Or a `<span>` element?